# koltin exposed - compare BigDecimal / decimal column with zero

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

how should i verify, if a decimal / BigDecimal columt type is zero?

```
fun foo():Op<Boolean> = UserTable.debt eq BigDecimal.ZERO
```

I want to avoid this kind of comparison:

```
BigDecimal("0.00").equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

Comment: Why don't you do: _BigDecimal("0.00") == BigDecimal.ZERO_

Comment: please pay attention my question refers to kotlin exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to avoid the problem where equivalent `BigDecimal`s in Java are not considered equal because of trailing zeros.

Note that the actual comparison will be performed by the database. If you are using PostgreSQL, the comparison via `eq` is correct. It is probably correct for other databases, but you should consult the documentation for your database and/or perform some tests to make sure that the comparison behaves the way you expect.